# Neptunes Sound (Pharrell and Chad Hugo in the early 00s)

Tags: sound-design

Asked this on KVR but got a confusing response.
The sounds used by Pharrell and Chad hugo. Some kind of horn. Tyler the Creator managed to emulate the sound in "Everyones a star" in his song "Sarah" towards the end.

First Sound

(Everyones a Star)

(Sarah)

Any help getting this sound in massive?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a saxophone to be honest. Maybe it is re-pitched a bit in Melodyne or it is sampled and played. or just a very sloppy player :)

Peace